# How can i make this flexbox container scroll instead of adapting the width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I want to make the flexbox container be 100%width and have a scrollbar to see the overflowing content. Now it seems to adapt the content to the width of the window and it always takes 100% of width with the content not overflowing at all.

https://codepen.io/UrsuGrizzly/pen/BmqPvm
https://jsfiddle.net/duvq2e42/

```
<div id="topimg">
 <a href="#" id="st1"></a>
 <a href="#" id="second"></a>
 <a href="#" id="first"></a>
 <a href="#" id="third"></a>
 <a href="#" id="fourth"></a>
 <a href="#" id="fifth"></a>
 <a href="#" id="sixth"></a>
 <a href="#" id="nd2"></a>
 <a href="#" id="rd3"></a>
 <a href="#" id="th4"></a>
</div>

#topimg {
 display: flex;
 min-width:100%;
 overflow-x:scroll;
}

#topimg > * {
 margin: 0 4px 0 0;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
}

#topimg #st1 {
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 125px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #nd2 {
 background-color: orange;
 width: 100px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #rd3 {
 background-color: cyan;
 width: 100px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #th4 {
 background-color:green;
 width: 100px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #first {
 background-color: purple;
 width: 100px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #second {
 background-color: red;
 width: 250px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #third {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 200px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: top;
}

#topimg #fourth {
 background-color: fuchsia;
 width: 250px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #fifth {
 background-color: brown;
 width: 100px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}

#topimg #sixth {
 background-color: coral;
 width: 100px;
 height: 144px;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a flex item's `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`, it is allowed to shrink, and it does, unless its content prevents it to do so.

Add `flex-shrink: 0;` to your `#topimg > *` rule

Stack snippet

```css
    #topimg {
     display: flex;
     min-width:100%;
     overflow-x:scroll;
    }

    #topimg > * {
     margin: 0 4px 0 0;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
     flex-shrink: 0;                                    /*  added  */
    }

    #topimg #st1 {
     background-color: yellow;
     width: 125px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #nd2 {
     background-color: orange;
     width: 100px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #rd3 {
     background-color: cyan;
     width: 100px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #th4 {
     background-color:green;
     width: 100px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #first {
     background-color: purple;
     width: 100px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #second {
     background-color: red;
     width: 250px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #third {
     background-color: blue;
     width: 200px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: top;
    }

    #topimg #fourth {
     background-color: fuchsia;
     width: 250px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #fifth {
     background-color: brown;
     width: 100px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }

    #topimg #sixth {
     background-color: coral;
     width: 100px;
     height: 144px;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="topimg">
          <a href="#" id="st1"></a>
          <a href="#" id="second"></a>
          <a href="#" id="first"></a>
          <a href="#" id="third"></a>
          <a href="#" id="fourth"></a>
          <a href="#" id="fifth"></a>
          <a href="#" id="sixth"></a>
          <a href="#" id="nd2"></a>
          <a href="#" id="rd3"></a>
          <a href="#" id="th4"></a>
</div>
```

---

As a comparison, if the links were the content, wrapped, it would work as is.

Stack snippet

```css
#topimg {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#topimg > * {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
}

#topimg #st1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 125px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #nd2 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #rd3 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #th4 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #first {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #second {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #third {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
}

#topimg #fourth {
  background-color: fuchsia;
  width: 250px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #fifth {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#topimg #sixth {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100px;
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="topimg">
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="st1"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="second"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="first"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="third"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="fourth"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="fifth"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="sixth"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="nd2"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="rd3"></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="th4"></a>
  </span>
</div>
```